# Validate XML response against WSDL using Ruby Savon

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, savon

I am using Ruby/Cucumber/Savon to automate Soap webservice. I need to validate the response against the wsdl file. Savon docs don't mention validating XML response anywhere. Does anyone know a good solution to doing this?

Thanks,
Harv Gill

Answer (score 2):

The excellent [Nokogiri library](http://www.nokogiri.org/) supports [XML schema (XSD) validation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Schema) which is used for SOAP messages (i.e. the "Types" section of the WSDL should contain a reference or inline XSD).

```ruby
xsd = Nokogiri::XML::Schema(File.read(SCHEMA_FILE))
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(XML_FILE))

xsd.validate(doc).each do |error|
  puts error.message
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My wsdl contains inline XSD. When I try to use the wsdl file in place of the SCHEMA_FILE, I get an error that says, "schema.rb:37:in `from_document': The XML document 'in_memory_buffer' is not a schema document. (Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError)"

Comment: @HarvGill: yes, a WSDL file is not an XSD file.  You'll have to extract the schema from the containing document.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/wsdl_validator) to simplify this process. It should extract all schemas from the WSDL and import any if needed. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

```
require 'wsdl_validator'
wsld = WsdlValidator.new('path_to_wsdl')
# xml can be String, Nokogiri::XML::Document
wsdl.validate xml
```

This will return true if valid or raise an exception with the error message if it's not.

You can get the XML from a Savon response and pass by the following

```
wsdl = 'path_to_wsdl'
client = Savon::Client.new(wsdl: wsdl)  
response = client.call(:operation, message: { element: 'value' })
WsdlValidator.new(wsdl).validate response.xml
```